# Staging area for JSON filled views

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, angularjs

I have a SPA webapp that calls a webservice to gather 'X' amount of json objects ~(1 - 30+). I then use this data for multiple changing slides (all data is not displayed in the 1st slide).

I am using Node/Express/Angular/Jade.

How should I stage these slides when I gather the original data from the webservice (can only call the service once because $ constraints)? I would like the back button/urls to work as well. So, should I completely render out the data and use client side JS to hide/show the dom elements based on button clicks (incorporating messy hash bangs and JS methods to track location/flow). Or is there a sexier more efficient way? Should I store my data in the cache and pull from it (using my angularjs ng-view, note: changing my ng-view will be a pain... it would be ideal to have a ng-view within a ng-view in this particular situation, even though that doesnt exist) based on the slide? Or is there another way?

Thank you for your help, let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: is there a template for slides or the slides are all different?

Comment: @Abhi There are four types of templates. An object within the JSON data will be used as a signal for which template to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mapping URLs to your angularjs pages, I would suggest using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).  You may or may not need ui-router for this particular problem.  But, generally, it will help tremendously in organizing the structure of your site.

For the other questions:

I would store your results (which was retrieved from the service) in a $rootScope variable.  The page index of your slides will be a parameter in your URL.  Based on the value of this parameter, your controller can decide which page content it will display.